# ActionScript display zero value

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

`public class myObject{`
`private var numVar:Number`
`}`

My AS file:
`var temp:MyObject`
`temp.numVar = 0;`

When I debug, `temp.numVar` contains a value of `0`, but does not show anything on the UI.  If this object is then saved to the DB, and then displayed to the UI, it shows a `0`.  My question is - how do I get `temp.numVar` to display `0` before persistenting it to the DB?

Comment: You should really post your actionscript code so that we can have a better idea of what you're actually doing.

Comment: wow that was totally different from what you wrote the first time (take your time to write your question properly ) :S. What UI does it have to be displayed by ?

Comment: not sure i understand what you mean by 'what UI does it have to be displayed by?'

Comment: Is it in a text field ? a Text Box ? What part of your code makes it available to the UI. The above just shows the class and the assignment .

Comment: it's a text field, which is being populated by the numVar attribute of the backing class MyObject.

Comment: What did the debug show at this point txtfield.txt = temp.numVar; (Also your numVar is private so you should use getter/setter methods instead)

Comment: It says the value of txtfield.txt is '0'.  (I am using getters/setters).

Comment: I cannot really say what it going on , maybe the flow of operations maybe try following the stack in debug but currently the code presented does not give the hints to where the problem could be . Sorry :(

Comment: i know.  i'm pretty perplexed myself.   thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the value of `temp.numVar` to a string before you send it to the TextField.

See my example:

```
var numVar:Number = 0;

someTextField.appendText(String(temp.numVar));
```

Comment: i'm setting all the values on the backing object in the AS, and then the backing object is being used to display the properties on the screen.  so since, the attribute `numVar` is of type Number, i cannot convert it to a string.

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by "backing object"? I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: the properties of `MyObject` are being set in AS, and then it is sent to the UI, and the attributes of `MyObject` are used to populate the fields on the UI.  when the attributes of `MyObject` are being set, `numVar` is set to a zero value.

Comment: Do you have access to the UI code? It would help a lot if you could provide more code.

Comment: i'm using a framework that takes care of the UI presentation.  and i don't have the source for that.

but on the same topic, although the 0 value doesn't show up when using a new object, when it is saved into the database, it persists as an actual 0 value, and then when i'm grabbing the data from the DB, (using the same procedure - putting the values on the attributes of the object, and then passing it to the UI), the 0 value is displayed on the screen.  i've seen that the Number datatype in AS treats 0 and null as the same.  do you think this has anything to do with my issue?